# remote connect to xampp website(v3.2.2)

Tags: xampp

I try to connect to my computer xampp website from other computer.
I got my IV4 IP, it works from local but not work from other computer.
my xampp version is v3.2.2
seems like there's no version available right now.
how can I set for it?
thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the LAN line, most routers allow any connections between peers, but I think you're trying to connect from outside that WiFi/router, yes?

If so, you need to get the public IP of the host computer running xampp (Google 'what is my ip'), then you'll need to port forward your local ip (192.168.1. something) and the port of xampp by going into your router settings. Port forwarding basically tells your router that outside connections should be allowed if they're using that IP and port. You'll then use the public IP and port in your browser from any device to see the website.

Comment: thanks for help
now I'm using rgnok to solve the problem:)